# Change IPv4 address of my server

Tags: networking, server, ipv4

I've tried to change de IPv4 address from my Ubuntu Server but when i run the command "netplan apply" an error appear, the error appeared is telling me my gateway isn't a valid IPv4 Address. Someone can help me please.
I'm a beginner with servers. I know this is a such idiot thing but i realy have difficult to do that IP migration. Tnx for the patient guys.

(Sorry for my Bad English i'm from Brazil.)
 The yaml file is:

```
network:
  version: "2"
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: 
      -190.115.196.57/26
      gateway4: 190.115.196.1/26
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.2.2.4]
      routes:
      - to: 51.161.15.254/32
        via: 0.0.0.0
        scope: link
```

The IP of the router is:
51.161.15.254

Comment: What is the IP address of your router?

Comment: I consulted the ip of router and the ip is 51.161.15.254

Comment: Please edit the question and add this info. It is important that the question has all the details. Where did the IP you are using for gateway come from?

Comment: Are you sure that the 26 and 32 at the end of the IP addresses is the correct value? Generally speaking, /32 means that the network has only a single IPv4 address and all traffic will go directly between the device with that IPv4 address and the default gateway. The device would not be able to communicate with other devices on the local subnet.

Comment: Yes, about this is correctly and propositaly, this is a server running from a rented machine localized in another space where other machines are disponibilized to other people, the unic access open from this server is the SSH access or by the dashboard of provider, i requested a migration for the provider and they sent the IP to configure at the serve. I'm started questioning about the IP whose the provider sent me.

Comment: Thanks @David you're correctly, i removed the /26 from the mask and that worked :) Thank u men, for the patient and to help me to resolve my problemn

Comment: The 26 from the gateway line is the one you removed?

Comment: Yes, the gateway line

Comment: OK I will make an actual answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the /26 at the end of the IP address was causing that address to be evaluated by a number of bits.

A “/26” network provides 64 IP 4 addresses. This was interpenetrated by netplan apply as an invalid address.

By not having the /26 the address is seen as a normal IP 4 address.

So in summary, and in non-CS degree terms, the slash notation tells us how many bits are used in that address (we can't change), and ultimately what is left for us to assign out specifically.

Without the /26 the gateway works as expected.

I am sure there could be a far more tech answer but I think this should suffice.